# Yahoo business mail - All of sudden - The server response was: 5.7.1 Authentication required

Tags: asp.net, smtpclient

I am using yahoo business mail as my smtp provider to send email from asp.net site hosted on IIS 7.5
All of sudden users are getting an error. My hosting provider says that it may be issue with yahoo servers. Any other idea what can be wrong? Below is error message and configuration of my web.config

System.Net.Mail.SmtpException
The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.1 Authentication required

System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.1 Authentication required
   at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String response)
   at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, Byte[] command, String from)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)

```
<system.net>
       <mailSettings>
     <smtp from="administrator@xxx.com">
                           <network host="98.139.221.242" port="25" enableSsl="false" userName="administrator@xx.com" password="xxx" defaultCredentials="false" />
                     </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy usesystemdefault="False"/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

I logged in with above email and password in yahoo and I was able to access the account.

Comment: This is third day and it is still broken. Futile attempts to contact yahoo support by email or phone.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if it's related to this somehow, from a Yahoo executive:

> Some of our users have not been able to access their mail since 10:27
>   PM PT on Monday night [11 Dec 2013], due to a hardware problem in one of our mail
>   data centers. The issue has been harder to fix than we originally
>   expected.

http://www.zdnet.com/yahoo-mails-it-woes-you-can-always-walk-away-7000024196/

For example, did they lose an authentication server, which caused your session to appear unauthenticated? It might be a different server from the one that authenticates your webmail login.

Comment: Seems like it -- OP, just inform your users of Yahoo's issues and that it is out of your hands.

Answer (score 0):

try to set port = 587 and EnableSsl = true, i got the same issue but in vb.net and it works with me.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

We are also having the problem wrt our yahoo business email id crashing. I am using yahoo business email since 2005 and last time one of my email account which was used to push email from my asp.net application was blocked without informing us. This caused a lot of problem on the usage of the application. I contacted yahoo support atleast 10 times and they were not able to help me. I then created another email account and made changes to the program to enable email push. Now I am faced with the authentication problem. This time if yahoo is not fixing this issue in a day I am forced to move our application and email accounts to GoDaddy